# Saving DOM-related data: $("element")[0].prop (or document.gEbyID("id_element").prop or even $("element").prop(prop)) vs $.data("element","prop")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

If the javascript element corresponding to a particular DOM object always refers to the same DOM object, and if accessing a property is faster than a function call, what is the benefit of `$.data()`?

I read somewhere something about `$.data()` preventing circular references to prevent memory leaks.

What sort of trickery when using a plain property might get me into that kind of trouble? Can somebody provide an example? If it is only IE that suffers from this issue perhaps this is a great way to encourage users to switch to better browsers!

I'm also assuming that the only thing wrong with the property approach is these memory leaks, and also potentially clobbering DOM property names. Are there other concerns?

Comment: Did you read the docs? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: Well, the docs answered none of my questions, it only narrows the "I read somewhere" bit to "I read on the jQuery doc".

Comment: That's a pretty long title you have there.

Comment: @Derek Yup! I was surprised it let me keep typing. I was sure (on at least two occasions) that i wouldn't be able to add one more alternative

Comment: do you really think that edge case memory leaks are going to interest  John Q Public enough to switch browsers??

Comment: Yes. In a FAQ page: "Q: This site stops working for me after doing X and Y on Z page...  A: Are you on IE7? This is a known issue and for gobbledygook reason we cannot rectify it. Download a new browser and this will never happen again!" No, seriously though i guess that was a joke. I honestly don't care about catering to any IE<9 users of my software though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If it is only IE that suffers from this issue perhaps this is a great way to encourage users to switch to better browsers!

There is no great way to do that.

> If the javascript element corresponding to a particular DOM object always refers to the same DOM object, and if accessing a property is faster than a function call, what is the benefit of $.data()?

Access to HTML5 data attributes, and removal of the reference when the element is removed from the DOM.